# Find the actors who DID NOT act with Hugo Weaving but acted with his co-stars, and SET a property act with value as didnot on those actors

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find the actors who DID NOT act with Hugo Weaving but acted with his co-stars, and SET a property act with value as didnot on those actors.

What I have done so far is this:

```
Match (p: Person), (other: Person), (m: Movie)
where (NOT (:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p)) 
AND  (p)- [:ACTED_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
set other.act = 'didnot'
return distinct other
```

This gives me the result (top 5 rows).:

```
╒══════════════════════════════╕
│"other"                       │
╞══════════════════════════════╡
│{"act":"didnot","born":1964,"n│
│ame":"Keanu Reeves"}          │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"act":"didnot","born":1967,"n│
│ame":"Carrie-Anne Moss"}      │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"act":"didnot","born":1961,"n│
│ame":"Laurence Fishburne"}    │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"act":"didnot","born":1978,"n│
│ame":"Emil Eifrem"}           │
├──────────────────────────────┤
│{"act":"didnot","born":1975,"n│
│ame":"Charlize Theron"}       │
```

The result is incorrect and also the query looks inefficient. What am I doing wrong?
Any insight in right direction is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code, it gives me 48 such actors.

```
MATCH(hw:Person{name:"Hugo Weaving"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(co:Person)
WITH hw, co
MATCH (co)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(co2:Person)
WHERE co2.name <> "Hugo Weaving"
AND NOT (co2)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(hw)
RETURN DISTINCT co2.name
```

Few of them are:

```
"David Morse"
"Sam Rockwell"
"Gary Sinise"
"James Cromwell"
"Bonnie Hunt"
"Patricia Clarkson"
"Michael Clarke Duncan"
....
```